# How do I install a network printer on all workstations for all users from Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition?

Tags: windows-server-2003, network-printer

I have a handful of workstations with users that log on to any of them with their account. I need to install a printer for all the users to use on any machine. The printer is already on the network and I can add the printer per user manually, but I need to do this from the server as there are many users and it'd be impossible to do it any other way.

Comment: This is a pretty complex task to accomplish. I was hoping for a more step by step set of directions to help speed up the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way, yes it wasn't quite the best solution but it sure saved me the time of figuring out how to use group policy. I followed the directions on this page: http://members.shaw.ca/bsanders/NetPrinterAllUsers.htm with the exception of I had to log into each workstation as the administrator and install the printer manually for the script to run. Otherwise I would get an error stating: "Unable to add the per machine printer connection. The print spooler service is not running." Even though the spooler was running on both the workstations and the server. After I logged in and installed the printer manually, the script would run and every user that logs into the machine gets the printer added to their profile.

Comment: Just a heads-up. Time spent learning Group Policy is time well-spent. You should really learn to use the tools that come with the system. They will serve you well.

Answer (score 5):

Do you have an AD domain? If so you can add a Domain Printer through group policy, and set it up on each machine with a logon script (also configured through group policy).
[This tutorial](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Managing-Printers-Group-Policy-Part1.html) (Specifically: [Part 2 of it](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/windows-2003/Managing-Printers-Group-Policy-Part2.html)) should get you started. Windows Help should fill in the blanks from there.

Comment: I read this article and the second part of it and don't see how this relates to Demi's question directly. It addresses configuring printer policies, but not deploying printers to machines.

Comment: @DavidMackey There used to be a link to [Part 2](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/windows-2003/Managing-Printers-Group-Policy-Part2.html) from that page which is where the magic bits are -- basically you need to do some hackery with a logon script to make sure the printers are added for the user (otherwise they have to browse/search the directory for the printer & add it manually - *bleh*). (Also see Cheekaleak's answer which links to another article on the same site).

Answer (score 3):

Your best best it to use a GPO to push out the Printer through logon script:

http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Deploying-Printers-Group-Policy-Windows-R2.html

^^ voretaq7 beat me to it.